# Serving original content if translation is missing, trouble in query WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, internationalization, translation

I'm trying to build up a method to provide a translation, which can fall back to serve the original text whenever a translation isn't found.

I have some "standard" tables which hold the various kind of content (posts, menus, etc) in the original language, and then a "master" translation table which holds the translated values, identified by a language key, a content type reference and the id of the translated item.

For example:

table_posts

```
id |     title      |    slug
-------------------------------
 8 | test contenuto | test-contenuto
```

table_translation

```
 id |      title    |  slug        | item_id | item_type | language
 ----------------------------------------------------
 1  | test content  | test-content |    8    |    1      |    2
```

I quite managed to make it work when searching for id, or without where clauses, but I'm stuck whenever I need to search based on the slug. What I'd like is that, if the slug is "about-us" but there's not entry in the translation table it should search for the respective content in the original language, or viceversa.

I managed so far using IFNULLs (or COALESCEs) to serve the content found, but I can't workout a reliable method to put in the WHERE condition.

This query. for example, works:

```
SELECT c.id,
  COALESCE(
    (SELECT t.slug FROM translations t WHERE t.id_item = c.id
    AND t.item_type = 1 AND t.language= 2), c.slug
   ) slug, 
  COALESCE( 
    (SELECT t.testo FROM translations t WHERE t.id_item = c.id
    AND t.item_type = 1 AND t.language= 2), c.testo
   ) testo,
    FROM content c
   WHERE c.type= 2 AND c.status = 1 AND c.trash = 0
```

For a query like this, instead, I really can't work out:

```
  SELECT cat.id,
  COALESCE (
     (SELECT t.name FROM translations t WHERE t.id_item = cat.id
      AND t.item_type = 2 AND t.language = 2), cat.name
     ) name
  FROM product_categories cat 
  WHERE cat.slug =....
```

I can't for the life of me tell it to search for a translated slug, and if not found in the translation table, get the original slug and use that to get the translated content (if there is, otherwise get the origial).

I hope I made myself clear on how it should work...My worrings, now,is that I took the problem from a wrong angle, and there are much easier way to solve this. I tried looking at third-party code, like the "JoomFish" extension for Joomla, to see how it works but that's a tripudium of loops and inner loops, I can't really follow it.

Is there a better way to solve this? How is it done usually? Do i need to refactor the whole DB schema, say using a table for each language?

**Edit:**

I'm using the WHERE clause to search for the specified records, in the translation table, which has that slug; if not found it it means either we're looking the site in the original language, or we're looking it another language but the translation (for that piece) is missing.
All in all, my intent is this:

I have URL which are made only by slugs. So how do I search for content when the slug is in another language?

Comment: It is not very clear what you want to accomplish. In the second query you are trying to use the WHERE to filter on what? The product_categories and content table, should be defined like the table_posts ?

Comment: @il_guru edited my answer. Yes, I'm using the wher to filter by slug

Comment: I would suggest a join to avoid subquery, however COALESCE seems to me to be necessary

Answer (score 0):

I would try `IF()`.

What about this query:

```sql
SELECT cat.id,
    (SELECT t.name 
        FROM translations t 
        WHERE t.id_item = cat.id
            AND t.item_type = 2 
            AND t.language = 2
    ) translation,
    IF(translation, translation, cat.name) as name
FROM product_categories cat 
WHERE cat.slug =....
```

Anyway, this is kinda unconvenient way of having translations... More common way is to have translations per table, that way You only need one select to fetch the data.
Usually You have a table `category` and the one containing translations like `category_description` or `category_text`, etc. Here You store per one row all the translations (name, description, slug, keywords, tags, etc).

It is also upon administration part of an application to ensure there won't be an entry withou translation when You have some languages set - You should set the main language and then when storing a record of category check whether there is a translation for other languages and if not I would copy the translations from the main language (that should always be set).

Answer (score 0):

I think `COALESCE` is the easiest way to perform your task, however you could use a `JOIN` to avoid the *subquery* and improve performance using a `WHERE` on *slug* only.

```
SELECT cat.id, COALESCE(t.name, cat.name) name
FROM product_categories cat
LEFT OUTER JOIN translations t 
ON t.id_item = cat.id AND t.item_type = 2 AND t.language = 2
WHERE cat.slug =....
```

Comment: My problem is the WHERE clause, I don't know how to set the condition and what to use. Do I use the original table? the translation? both upon conditions?

Comment: the slug you are looking to translate?

Comment: I take the slug from the url, we might be in the Enlish side and the slug is translated, or in the English side and the slug is still the original, or in the original side. How can the WHERE works notwhistanding which slug (original or translated) is passed? I think I'm making it more difficult than it should be....

Comment: If you put in the WHERE the slug you are looking for, the query i provided should work as desired; did you try it? If does not work, could you provide an example of the URL you read, the slug you look for on the db, the db content and the result you want? Because i think i'm missing some point :)